# [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: function split_part(...) does not exist

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm trying to run below query in redshift

```
select row_number() over(order by 1) as assignment_tag_id   , 
   user_id as user_id   , 
   split_part(t.assignment, ',', numbers.num) as assignment 
from cardlytics_test t 
join numbers on numbers.num <= regexp_count(t.assignment, ',\\s') + 1
```

but it's throwing the error

> Amazon Invalid operation: function split_part(character varying, character varying, double precision) does not exist;

What's wrong with the query?

Comment: Cast numbers.num to an int: `numbers.num::int`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select row_number() over(order by 1) as assignment_tag_id   , 
   user_id as user_id   , 
   split_part(t.assignment, ',',cast (numbers.num as int)) as assignment 
from cardlytics_test t 
join numbers on numbers.num <= regexp_count(t.assignment, ',\\s') + 1
```

Third argument in split_part(string,delimiter,**part**) has to be an integer and from the error code I presume you are passing float. 
**Part**- Position of the portion to return (counting from 1). Must be an integer greater than 0. If part is larger than the number of string portions, SPLIT_PART returns an empty string.
If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.